# How to remove my nested ternary expressions in my code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to clean up my code but I can't.  I would like to get rid of the nested ternary expressions. I work with react js 17.0.2. Do you have any ideas to help me?

```js
  const buildNewFilters = (query, filtersIndex: Array<string>) => {
    const newFilters = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < filtersIndex.length; i++) {
      newFilters[filtersIndex[i]] = router.query[filtersIndex[i]] ? typeof router.query[filtersIndex[i]] == ('string' || 'number') ? [router.query[filtersIndex[i]]] : router.query[filtersIndex[i]] : undefined
      if (filtersIndex[i] === 'designers' && newFilters.designers) {
        newFilters.designers = newFilters.designers.map(designer => parseInt(designer));
      }
    }
    return newFilters;
  };
```

Comment: use if statements??

Comment: Yes because my linter say me : Do not nest ternary expressions. eslint (no-nested-ternary)

Comment: So use if statements. `foo = a ? b : c;` is `let foo; if(a) { foo = b; } else { foo = c; }`

Comment: exactly but I don't know how to do it

Comment: So what is one of your attempted fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (router.query[filtersIndex[i]]) {
   if (typeof router.query[filtersIndex[i]] == ("string" || "number")) {
     newFilters[filtersIndex[i]] = [router.query[filtersIndex[i]]];
    } else {
      newFilters[filtersIndex[i]] = router.query[filtersIndex[i]];
    }
  } else {
    newFilters[filtersIndex[i]] = undefined;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, the code works !!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not used to working with ternary operators, I understand that it's not easy to refactor the code. First, you can read about what ternary expressions are and try them out in the [Mozilla Documentation about ternary operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). Basically the part of the code before the `?` evaluates to either `true` or `false` and if it evaluates to `true`, the part before the subsequent `:` is executed (in your case assigned to the variable `newFilters[filtersIndex[i]]`, otherwise the part after the `:` will be assigned to the variable.

My tip would be to put the line you want to refactor in a text editor to experiment with it, and add line breaks and/or tabs after the `?` and `:` signs to see the structure better and to see what is happening at each step.